# Sorting only first character, along a specific order

Tags: r, sorting

I have a character vector like this:

```
stuff <- c("3S", "AH", "2I", "B4", "AL")
```

And I have a "position" vector like this:

```
pos <- c("3", "B", "A", "2")
```

I want to use the last vector as a reference to sort the first one by looking only at the first character of each element; I don't care about the second character. That is, I want to write and a function like `specialsort(stuff, pos)`, and my result should be `c("3S", "B4", "AH", "AL", "2I")`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `substring` to extract the first letter of `stuff` and `match` to match your vector against the reference:

```
# find index in pos
i <- match(substring(stuff, 1, 1), pos)

# order by pos
o <- order(i)

stuff[o]
# [1] "3S" "B4" "AH" "AL" "2I"
```

Comment: It's not obscene as a one liner: `stuff[order(match(substr(stuff,1,1),pos))]`

Comment: I realy loved those two equivalent solutions. The two liner is very instructive for a newcomer to R like me. The equivalent oneliner is beautiful. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm almost sure there's a simpler way to do it but this works:

```
specialsort <- function(stuff, pos) {
  stuff.pos <- sapply(pos,function(x) which(substring(stuff,1,1) == x))
  stuff[unlist(stuff.pos)]
}

specialsort(stuff,pos)
```

Careful though: This (and many other solutions) implicitly assumes that the pos vector is unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a clever (if I may say myself) manipulation involving the transposition to `factors`:

```
stuff[order(factor(sapply(stuff,function(x)unlist(strsplit(x,''))[1]),levels=pos))]
```

**edited to add some explanations and simplify:**

The first part would be to isolate only the first character of your stuff vector. This can be done with:

```
> sapply(stuff,function(x)unlist(strsplit(x,''))[1])
 3S  AH  2I  B4  AL 
"3" "A" "2" "B" "A"
```

Then, you can convert this to factors, using your vector `pos` as levels:

```
> factor(sapply(stuff,function(x)unlist(strsplit(x,''))[1]),levels=pos)
3S AH 2I B4 AL 
 3  A  2  B  A 
Levels: 3 B A 2
```

Finally, you can get the right order from these factors:

```
> order(factor(sapply(stuff,function(x)unlist(strsplit(x,''))[1]),levels=pos))
[1] 1 4 2 5 3
```

The finish is simply taking a subset from your original `stuff` vector:

```
> stuff[order(factor(sapply(stuff,function(x)unlist(strsplit(x,''))[1]),levels=pos))]
[1] "3S" "B4" "AH" "AL" "2I"
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
stuff <- c("3S", "AH", "2I", "B4", "AL")
pos <- c("3", "B", "A", "2")

stuff.df = data.frame(stuff,pos = substr(stuff,1,1))
merge(data.frame(pos),stuff.df,sort = F)
```

The "pos" column of the sorted data.frame is what you want